# fetch chromium - No such file or directory

Tags: chromium

I've cloned depot tools given instructions from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git/) on ubuntu 17.04.

When I run fetch chromium I get the following error.

```
    ./fetch chromium
Running: gclient root
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fetch.py", line 299, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "./fetch.py", line 294, in main
    return run(options, spec, root)
  File "./fetch.py", line 280, in run
    if not options.force and checkout.exists():
  File "./fetch.py", line 82, in exists
    gclient_root = self.run_gclient('root').strip()
  File "./fetch.py", line 78, in run_gclient
    return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)
  File "./fetch.py", line 68, in run
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have come across similar errors in stackoverflow while searching for a resolution however none of them helped resolve the problem.

I'm not clear on if there is any steps required after cloning to install depot tools? The readme

Any thoughts on what is required to solve the problem?
Conteh